# Form control is lost while downloading the data in c# windows application

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

I have created a windows application in c# in which I download results from the given url.But downloading of results is a long process and my windows form freezes and I lose control of form.While data is being download I can't even move or minimize the form.I have kept a progress bar on form which is updated but I have no control of form. I created a child thread on the method which I call to download the data but this thread can't update the progress bar.I tried but could not use the background worker(as it says cross thread communication not allowed)
Is there any way by which I can keep the progress bar on the same form with out loosing the control of that form?

Thanks in advance  sir!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `WebClient`

`webClient.DownloadString(uri)` or `webClient.DownloadData(uri)` or `webClient.DownloadFile(uri)`

try using this instead

`webClient.DownloadStringAsync(Uri)` or `webClient.DownloadDataAsync(Uri)` or `webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri)`

The asynchronous methods have some completed event handlers, for eg. `DownloadFileCompleted`, that you could use tell when the download is complete.

As your the "cross-thread operation not valid" error, read [this post](http://c-sharp-programming.blogspot.com/2008/07/cross-thread-operation-not-valid.html).

Comment: +1 - I'm not really a .NET guy - this looks like the correct way to do what I described - the .NET way...

Answer (score 0):

Are you building a web app? If so, I'd recommend using a client side code for the progress bar, and let the server handle the operation of returning the payload - could even return it with AJAX.

If it's not a web application, I'd suggest spinning off one of the operations on a separate thread. You can use a class scoped variable to relay progress to your progress bar.